# C++ exception thrown

Tags: c++, exception

I am learning C++ and have lost quite some time trying to solve to understand the reason of the error i am getting.
When i run the code below i am getting an Exception thrown. It happens when the program ends, so i believe it's related to the Edge pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


struct Edge {
    int src, dest;
};

class Graph {
    
public:
    int V, E;
    Edge *edge = new Edge[E * sizeof(Edge)];
    Graph(int Ver, int Edg);
};

Graph::Graph(int Ver, int Edg) {
    V = Ver;
    E = Edg;
}


Graph* createGraph(int V, int E) {

    Graph* graph = new Graph(V,E);
    return graph;
}

int find(int* parents, int val) {
    if (parents[val] == -1)
        return val;
    return find(parents, parents[val]);
}

void Union(int *parents, int x, int y) {
    parents[x] = y;
}


int isCycle(Graph* graph) {

    int* parents = new int[graph->V * sizeof(int)];

    memset(parents, -1, graph->V * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < graph->E; i++) {
        int x = find(parents, graph->edge[i].src);
        int y = find(parents, graph->edge[i].dest);

        if (x == y) {
            return 1;
        };

        Union(parents, x, y);
    }


    return 0;
}



int main()
{

    int V = 9, E = 8;
    Graph* graph = createGraph(V, E);


    graph->edge[0].src = 0;
    graph->edge[0].dest = 1;

    graph->edge[6].src = 0;
    graph->edge[6].dest = 6;

    graph->edge[5].src = 0;
    graph->edge[5].dest = 7;

    graph->edge[1].src = 1;
    graph->edge[1].dest = 2;

    graph->edge[2].src = 3;
    graph->edge[2].dest = 2;

    graph->edge[3].src = 4;
    graph->edge[3].dest = 3;

    graph->edge[4].src = 4;
    graph->edge[4].dest = 5;

    graph->edge[7].src = 5;
    graph->edge[7].dest = 7;

    if (isCycle(graph))
        cout << "graph contains cycle";
    else
        cout << "graph doesn't contain cycle";

    return 0;
}
```

I started learning C++ only few months ago, can somebody help me to understand why I am getting that exception?

Comment: Try to debug your code.

Comment: At the time `new Edge[E * sizeof(Edge)]` is executed, `E` is not initialized yet. The program therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks Igor you are absolutely right!
Initialising edge = new Edge[Edg * sizeof(Edge)];
in the constructor solved the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding pointers unless you just need to point to something. Your `createGraph` shouldn't exist—callers can just use the constructor: `Graph graph(V, E);`. `edge` (prefer plurals for collections) can simply be `std::vector<Edge>` to fix the memory leak you've got in every `Graph` object. `parents` can again be a `std::vector<int>`—you're leaking more memory there. The pointer parameters could be references since you assume they aren't null, and they can be `const` if you aren't modifying them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Edge *edge = new Edge[E * sizeof(Edge)];
```

Unless `E` is initialized, this multiplies an uninitalized variable by `sizeof(Edge)` (which is also wrong on its face value as well, but we'll get to it later). This is undefined behavior.

```
Graph::Graph(int Ver, int Edg) {
    V = Ver;
    E = Edg;
}
```

This isn't good enough. The default values of class members, if specified, are used to initialize them ***before*** the constructor's body starts running.

The proper way to do this is to use the constructor's ***initialization section***:

```
Graph::Graph(int Ver, int Edg) : V{Ver}, E{Edg}  { }
```

This initializes `V` and `E` first.

Now consider:

```
Edge *edge = new Edge[E * sizeof(Edge)];
```

So here, `E` is now initialized, fixing one problem. But this is still incorrect. It's clear, based on the rest of the code, that this should really be:

```
Edge *edge = new Edge[E];
```

In C++, when you wish to declare an array of, say, 4 integers, all you have to do is declare:

```
int n[4];
```

The compiler takes care of multiplying 4 by however many bytes it takes to hold an `int`. The same thing is true for the `new` statement. If your goal is to construct an array of #`E` `Edge`s, that would be, unsurprisingly: `new Edge[E]`. This same mistake occurs several times in the shown code.